# codeigniter rest api json routing

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest

I am trying to implement codeigniter rest api i am only getting xml output not json please guys help me out.

routing code:

```
$route['api'] = 'omega_api';
$route['api/makes/(:any)'] = 'omega_api/makes/$1';
$route['terms-and-conditions'] = 'home/terms_and_conditions';
$route['contact-us'] = 'home/contact_us';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

controller code:

```
    class omega_api extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('allcars_model');
    }

    public function makes_get($year) {
        $this->response($this->allcars_model->get_makes($year));
    }
}
```

model code:

```
Class allcars_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
public function get_makes($year) {
        return    $this->db->distinct()->select('om_allmakes.makeid,om_allmakes.make_name')->from('om_allmakes')->join('om_allcars', 'om_allmakes.makeid=om_allcars.model_make_id')->where('om_allcars.model_year = ', $year)->get()->result();
    }
}
```

so when i goto this url http://www.omegalocal.com/api/makes/2014/format/json it always gives me xml output as below:

```
<xml>
  <item>
    <makeid>3</makeid>
    <make_name>acura</make_name>
    </item><item><makeid>4</makeid>
    <make_name>Alfa Romeo</make_name>
  </item>
</xml>
```

I really dont get whats the problem guys but i think it has to do something with routing.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Delete all the routes, and see if it works then. Or, change the "rest_default_format" in the rest config file.

Comment: Hi craig i tried that still output in xml however in codeigniter rest api documentation it simply says format/json will give you json & format/xml gives you xml format but not in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try with query string format: `?format=json`

```
$route['api/makes/(:num)/format/(xml|json)'] = 'omega_api/makes/$1/?format=$2';
```

Comment: Hi bora i tried this it gives the same output in xml